# Rails routing error, Object being assigned to param key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have objects Quiz and Question.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz

  def to_param
    quesion_permalink
  end
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions

  def to_param
    permalink
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
match '/quizzes/:permalink/questions/:questions_permalink', to: 'questions#show', via: 'get', as: 'question'
```

When I put the link question_path(q) in the quiz#show page I get this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"questions", :action=>"show", :permalink=>#<Question id: 2, question: "Is Ruby a Scripting Language?", quiz_id: 2, question_permalink: "q1", created_at: "2013-12-28 21:36:25", updated_at: "2013-12-28 21:36:25", order: 1>, :questions_permalink=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:questions_permalink]
```

I see that the Question that I want to view is being set as an object to the `:permalink` key. Why is that and how would I make it so `:permalink` is the quiz permalink and `:question_permalink` is the question peramlink?

Comment: use get instead of match

Comment: run commqand rake routes on your terminal and find the exact url helper for that.

Comment: @SamD made no difference

Comment: @NitinJ that gives me `question_path` which I am using.

Comment: You have a typo in Question.to_param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route requires two parameters: `:permalink` and `:questions_permalink`. You'd need to pass an object for each parameter. Based on what you've posted, I presume the following would work:

```
question_path(quiz, question)
```